# Extern C method call from C#

Tags: c#, c, .net-2.0, .net-1.1, extern

I have a `C` library code, in which `extern` method is defined:

```
typedef unsigned int    U32;
extern U32 iw(U32 b, U32 p);
```

I also have the `Assembler` code, in which this method is defined.

How can I call this `C` (or may be even `Assembler`) method from C# code?
Can I use the [`DllImport` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like the following to call your C dll function:

```
[DllImport("your.dll", EntryPoint="iw")]
public static extern UInt32 NiceNameFunc(UInt32 niceNameA, UInt32 niceNameP);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just be aware that you need to consider calling conventions.  Most Win32 APIs are written to use `stdcall`, so `P/Invoke` uses `stdcall` by the default. However VC++ uses `CDecl` by default.

If you run into problems you can either modify your exported function to be `stdcall`, or you can modify your `P/Invoke` declaration (I think there's an optional `CallingConvention` argument to the `DllImport` attribute)